# Calculate dimension and find a base of the anti-image of a vectorial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $f:M_{2x3}(\mathbb R)\rightarrow\mathbb R^4$ defined as $f\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ i & j & k \end{pmatrix}=(a+b+c,a+i+k,b+j-k,c-i-j)$ and let $F \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ given by $F=\langle(1,2,1,0),(2,1,0,-1),(0,1,2,1)\rangle$, I'm asked to calculate the dimension and find a base of $f^{-1}(F)$. I don't even know how to start. Could you please give me a little hint?

Comment: At first I read that as "antimage". #dota2

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$
One way to compute dimensions is by rank-nullity. Let $G = f^{-1}(F)$ and let $f|_G$ denote the restriction of $f$ to $G$; then by rank nullity
$$ \dim G = \dim \im f|_G + \dim \ker f|_G. $$

We know that $\im f|_G \subset F$ because $G = f^{-1}(F)$ but unfortunately we don't know that equality holds (it doesn't). So we must do a little work to compute $\dim \im f|_G$.
We know (or rather, you can verify by checking inclusion both ways) that
$$\im f|_G = \im f \cap F. $$
We also know (by the the subspace formula, provable from rank-nullity or see http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2013/2631/39/LA-4-12.pdf) that
$$\dim (\im f + F) = \dim \im f + \dim F - \dim (\im f \cap F) $$
and you should be able to compute the 3 leftmost quantities.

To compute $\dim \ker f|_G$, observe that $\ker f|_G = \ker f$ (because $f^{-1}(0) \subset f^{-1}(F)$) and use rank-nullity.